# Question about closure on a variation of Moore Plane

Tags: general-topology

For the following question below.  I would like to ask to do the following two questions, am I to assume that the underlying topology is the standard euclidean metric topology?
Let $A=\{(x,y) \in R^{2}: y \geq 0\}$ and let $\mathcal{T}$ be the topology on $A$ as follows:

For each $z=(x,y)\in A$ with $y > 0$ and each $\epsilon$ with $0< \epsilon < y.$  Let $D(z, \epsilon)=\{(a,b) \in A: (x-a)^{2}+(y-b)^{2}<\epsilon^{2}\}.$  For each $(x,0)\in A$ and each $\epsilon > 0,$  Let $E((x,0),\epsilon)=\{(x,0)\} \cup \{(a,b) \in A:(x-a)^{2}+(y-b)^{2}<\epsilon^{2}\}.$

Find the closure for the following two sets: 
$\{(x,y)\in A:$x is rational and $y=0$$\}$
and
$\{(x,y)\in A:$x is irrational and $y=0$$\}$

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the subspace S = R×{0} of your plane is homeomorphic to R, both of those sets are dense subsets of S.  Hence within S, their closures are both S.  As S is a closed subset of A, both of those closures within A are S.

This is no surprise as your plane is homeomorphic to A as a subspace of the real plane.

The D and E definition of the topology of your plane is shabby.

Comment: by subspace $S= R\times\{0\}$ of the defined topology $\mathcal{T}$ is homeomorphic to $R$, do you mean the following:  as an example, if we take the first set, $\{(x,y)\in A:$x is rational and $y=0$$\} \subset S$ and $\mathcal{T}_{S}$ is a subspace topology of $T$, hence $\{(x,y)\in A:$x is rational and $y=0$$\}$ is homeomorphic to $R$.

Comment: That is right.  You've invented nothing.  Another interesting plane is the Nemytskii's tangent disk topology.

Comment: thank you for your explanation and clarifications.  My apologies for my late response.  I posed my questions pretty late and hence I felt asleep and just saw your response now.  Again, thank you.